# Coldfusion check field dynamically Compare len check vs eq ""

Tags: coldfusion

I have a test in a function to make sure the form fields are there.

Which of these would you use? and why?

1. instead of trim(form[arguments.fieldname]) eq ""
2. len(trim(form[arguments.fieldname])) eq 0

Is there a true benefit to either one over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are equivalent. The choice is one of style. Do note that those who prefer `len` tend to use the return value as an implicit boolean (so, `<cfif len(trim(form[arguments.fieldname]))>`, without the `eq 0`), and this does seem to be generally regarded as more expressive.

But both work, and the performance differences are negligible. It is a question of readability, which is somewhat subjective.

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864594/lenx-better-or-x-neq-better-in-cfml).

Comment: Also consider case when null is returned. Null is not "", so this condition might fail.